# My checkbox doesn't work with loop for to display data

Tags: javascript, php

I did the checkbox work good, this is my one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
        document.getElementById("srt").value = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
        }
        else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
        document.getElementById("srt").value = "";
        }
    });
});
```

At my display data part, I have the loop for to show all the record. I want after I click the checkbox the value I get from `document.getElementById("Ultra").value` and display on `document.getElementById("srt").value`. It work good at 1 record only, the rest I check didn't work. I think the problem is I display it on `<input type="text" id="srt">` and the textbox I put in loop with loop for to display database. Any help?

This one is php part:

```
for ( $v = 0 ; $v < mysql_num_rows($result) ; $v++ ) 
        {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    ?>
    <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
    <?php
    echo'<td>'.$row['aaa'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'.$row['bbb'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'.$row['ccc'].'</td>';             
    echo'<td><input type="text" id="srt"></td>';//////this one to display value i get           
    echo'<td>'.$row['dddr'].'</td>';            
    }
```

The value only display on 1 row only.

Comment: can you give us also the html and/or php code for the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I see is you have `<input type="text" id="srt">` in each loop. This means your ids are not unique and this could cause problems in the `document.getElementById("srt").value = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;` call.

Try make ids unique (this means giving a different id for every textbox, maybe something like `srt_'.$v.'` and also retrieving the correct textbox `id` in the jquery function)

PS: can you please show also the "Ultra" input in your php code?

Edit: to get the correct textbox you could set an id to your checkbox too and use it to get the correct id of the textbox.

In your page:

```
echo'<td><input type="checkbox" id='.$v.'/></td>';
```

and

```
echo'<td><input type="text" id="srt'.$v.'"></td>';
```

And in your function

```
if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
    document.getElementById("srt"+this.id).value = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
}
```

I did not test it so there could be something to adjust, but the idea is there.

Comment: Thank alot, the "Ultra" is a name of dropdown list, i get the value from it and put it into the textboxt. All of this into form, so when i click submit it will update in database. If i put srt_'.$v.' is id for textboxt then this part `document.getElementById("srt").value` the "srt" of javascrip what should i change ?

Comment: I put my textbox like`<input type="text" id="'.$v.'">` and javascrip part is `document.getElementById(i).value = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;`. Then all textbox is same, i want it display each row when i click

Comment: You have to understand which row you are in. You could add, for example, an attribute to your checkbox and use it to get the correct textbox. I edited the answer and added this bit

Comment: Thank for your help, but it now work, nothing appear, i didnt get the idea, still wonder this part `document.getElementById("srt"+this.id).value` this.id i have to change or just leave it ?

Comment: should work, but as i said it is not tested so i could have missed something. Try add some `alert` in js to see what's going on. If you create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) on that it would be easier to help

Comment: look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uv53b6Lc/3/). Does it work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var values = $('input.high_name:checked').map(function () {
  return this.value;
}).get(); 
alert(values);
});
```

and your checkbox add class name,

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="high[]" class="high_name">
```

Comment: Thank for reply, but i want it not work, i think the problem is the loop in my database, when i check the box, only 1 row have the value, the rest is not